# React Select Multi Select Check box -With Select All

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am looking for some React component which has feature of multi select check box along with select All option, I could see few components but it does not have select all built in Feature. Any pointers?

Comment: You could take a look at this https://react-select.com/home and you can implement custom "select all" button.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would need to use a controlled `value` and `onChange` props. As well as an `OnChange` one on your checkbox.

Below one way to do it:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./styles.css";

const options = [
  { label: "Option 1", value: 1 },
  { label: "Option 2", value: 2 },
  { label: "Option 3", value: 3 },
  { label: "Option 4", value: 4 },
  { label: "Option 5", value: 5 },
  { label: "Option 6", value: 6 },
  { label: "Option 7", value: 7 }
];
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: false,
      values: []
    };
  }
  onChangeCheckbox = e => {
    const isChecked = !this.state.checked;
    this.setState({
      checked: isChecked,
      values: isChecked ? options : this.state.values
    });
  };
  onChange = opt => {
    const allOptionsSelected = opt.length === options.length;
    this.setState({
      checked: allOptionsSelected ? true : false,
      values: opt
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          isMulti
          onChange={this.onChange}
          options={options}
          value={this.state.values}
        />
        <p>
          <input
            onChange={this.onChangeCheckbox}
            type="checkbox"
            id="selectAll"
            value="selectAll"
            checked={this.state.checked}
          />
          <label for="selectAll">Select all</label>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2zx89yp7).

Comment: thx Laura..we also followed the suggestion from this link and implemented ithttps://medium.com/@alex_escalante/react-select-alloptionoptions-with-a-single-click-1ebf5a33fe31